# Override Canonical Object in Plone

Tags: plone

I'd like to render an object's view in place of another object and yet keep the canonical path as the one originally traversed to so breadcrumbs and object tabs, etc all still act the same.

I know how to render the other object in place of the canonical one, but it almost seems impossible to override what is used for the canonical object unless I perhaps override the "canonical_object" method in the "plone_context_state" browser view.

Here is the code I have my view **call** method for rendering the other object:

```
item = aq_base(default_item).__of__(self.context)
layout = item.getLayout() or item.getDefaultLayout()
try:
    return aq_acquire(item, layout)(*args, **kwargs)
except AttributeError:
    try:
        return getMultiAdapter((item, self.request), name=layout)(*args, **kwargs)
    except: pass

return super(DefaultItemEnabledView, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, is it possible to make the canonical object used by plone the originally traversed one so breadcrumbs, object tabs, etc are applied appropriately?

Comment: Your blank except clause will cause problems in case of ZODB conflict errors; they'll be swallowed and much weirdness will ensue.

Comment: hhmm, well, nothing should be writing to the database on rendering a view so that shouldn't really happen. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You cannot assume all code will behave and not cause writes. ;-) Bottom line: blanket excepts in Zope are almost always going to bite you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that what you want is an impossible task; you are rendering the full chrome for a new context and everything will thus render using that context. You'd have to redo everything; breadcrumbs, actions, portlets, any other context-sensitive viewlets.

I am not sure what your use-case is that you have to support all possible layouts of arbitrary objects, you may have to rethink your options here.

If you do not have a use-case that requires all possible layouts to work, then you can just create a custom view for your canonical object that just re-renders the content well for the other object. Many views for content already include macros you can re-use, for example. Take a look at `skins/plone_content/folder_full_view_item.pt` for an example template that reuses such macros to render items in a folder for the `folder_full_view` template.

Comment: This is definitely the better way to go. Thank you for the advise.

Answer (score 1):

bda.contentproxy was a product that make this, but **be aware**... is a very complex task, full of problems behind the corner